# Skipping the Permission Check?

Tags: android, permissions

I am currently trying to make a location app.
However, I'm slightly  annoyed at how I need to go through a Permissions check every time I try to use a location service inside a method.

The question is, is there a way so that I can skip the permissions check, provided I have asked for permission in onCreate()?

This is the code where I am trying to call a location service:

```
protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, LocationRequest mLocationRequest, this);
    Location OldLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    String OldLocationTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Location NewLocation = location;
    String NewLocationTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());

}
```

And this is my permissions check I may need to add to every single method:

```
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
            GPSExplanation();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you set your target sdk 23+ you will need the permission on runtime. set it 22 and try.

Comment: "I'm slightly annoyed at how I need to go through a Permissions check every time I try to use a location service inside a method" -- um, you don't.

Comment: But OldLocation =LocationServices brings up with an error that says that it needs permission and prompts me to go through a permissions check.